# How can I force LilyPond to repeat a clef on every line of the score?

Tags: lilypond

I'd like LilyPond to print the clef not only at the beginning of the score, but whenever the line breaks, at the beginning of the new line. Is this possible at all, and, how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine prints the clef automatically on every line:

[image]

I simply used the `\break` command for a new line:

```
\relative c' {
  c d e f | \break
  g a b c |
}
```

Another example:

[image]

Comment: Okay, found the problem. Actually, I didn't realize that removing the barline_engraver also removed the clef symbols.